# Inserting table <td> cell under a particular header <th> from an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a Javscript Object:

```
var obj = {
  "results": [{
      "B": "Row 1 Col 2"
    }, {
      "A": "Row 2 Col 1"
      "B": "Row 2 Col 2"
    }, {
      "C": "Row 3 Coll 3"
    }
  }]
```

I wish to convert it to a table that looks like the following.

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="A">A</th>
      <th id="B">B</th>
      <th id="C">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which looks like:

[image]

More precisely, I'm looking for a way to somehow insert the value of a property directly below it. And creating a new header as when a new property emerges while successively reading the object. This is a better way of approaching the problem I feel, as it is more versatile for an arbitrary object.

This is why I was wondering if there was any HTML tag or jQuery way such that I can directly insert a cell under a particular header of my choice instead of calculating and inserting appropriate number of "`<td></td>`" till I get to the right cell.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kqsozme5/2/

Comment: why do you have `"results": [{ "A": "Row 1 Col 2"..` while it should be `Col 1` according to your explanation?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Oh I'm sorry. I've edited it.

Comment: Have you tried anything which fails ?

Comment: There are no shortcuts...you have to put in empty cells as needed or you will have alignment problems. What are the rules for setting headings sorting?

Comment: @RayonDabre I wanted to write the code for it. But I think it is quite ugly. Adding the appropriate `<td>` is something I find it to be dificult with jQuery

Comment: A hint: Use `For` loop and use `if..else` conditions

Comment: @VickyGonsalves That's the whole point isnt it. I was capable enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following doesn't care how many columns there are, and works on totally arbitrary object config.

It sorts the column names prior to looping through data again to build rows and creates empty cells as necessary

```
// create array of column keys and sort
var cols = obj.results.reduce(function(arr, currObj) {
    return arr.concat(Object.keys(currObj).filter(function(key) {
        return arr.indexOf(key) == -1
    }));
}, []).sort();
// create header from sorted column keys
var header = '<tr><th>' + cols.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';

var rows = obj.results.map(function(item) {
    // loop over column keys checking matches to item keys
    return '<tr>' +
        cols.map(function(key) {
            return '<td>' + (item.hasOwnProperty(key) ? item[key] : '') + '</td>';
        }).join('') + '</tr>';
}).join('');
var table = '<table  border="1">' + header + rows + '</table>';
```

```js
var obj = {
    "results": [{
        "B": "Row 1 Col 2"
    }, {
        "A": "Row 2 Col 1",
        "B": "Row 2 Col 2"
    }, {
        "C": "Row 3 Coll 3"
    }]
};

// create array of column keys and sort
var cols = obj.results.reduce(function(arr, currObj) {
    return arr.concat(Object.keys(currObj).filter(function(key) {
        return arr.indexOf(key) == -1
    }));
}, []).sort();
// create header from sorted column keys
var header = '<tr><th>' + cols.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';

var rows = obj.results.map(function(item) {
    // loop over column keys checking matches to item keys
    return '<tr>' +
        cols.map(function(key) {
            return '<td>' + (item.hasOwnProperty(key) ? item[key] : '') + '</td>';
        }).join('') + '</tr>';
}).join('');
var table = '<table  border="1">' + header + rows + '</table>';
$('body').append(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nailed it! I'll go through your code thoroughly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<tbody id = "idTBody">
```

Jquery:

```
for(var result in obj.results)
{
    for(var col in obj.results[result])
    {
        $("#idTBody").append("<tr>");
        if(col == 'A'){ $("#idTBody").append("<td>"+obj.results[result][col]+"</td>");}
        else {$("#idTBody").append("<td></td>");}
        if(col == 'B'){ $("#idTBody").append("<td>"+obj.results[result][col]+"</td>");}
        else {$("#idTBody").append("<td></td>");}
        if(col == 'C'){ $("#idTBody").append("<td>"+obj.results[result][col]+"</td>");}
        else {$("#idTBody").append("<td></td>");}
        $("#idTBody").append("</tr>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. The obj variable you have written in the fiddle is wrong. The brackets are misplaced. Second thing is that in fiddle select jquery in the javascript Frameworks and Extensions and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

why don't use arrays

```
var object = {
  result: [['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['', 'rows1 col2', ''],
           ['row2 col1', 'row2 col2', '']]
}
```

it's easy to convert to tables.

Comment: Yes, It is obviously much easier with arrays but I don't have a choice in that.

Comment: obj.results's length is rows number, and the max  of results's properties's length is the cols number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your Object is :

```
var obj = {
"results": [{
  "A": "",
  "B": "Row 1 Col 2",
  "C": ""
}, {
  "A": "Row 2 Col 1",
  "B": "Row 2 Col 2",
  "C": ""
}, {
  "A": "",
  "B": "",
  "C": "Row 3 Coll 3"
}
}]
```

HTML Would Be:

```
<table id="trialTable" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th id="A">A</th>
   <th id="B">B</th>
   <th id="C">C</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
 </table>
```

JQuery will Be:

```
var tbody = $("#trialTable > tbody");
tbody.empty();
$.each(obj.results, function(index, data) {
  var tr = $("<tr>");
  var td = $("<td>");

  tr.append($('<td>', {
        text: data.A
  }));
  tr.append($('<td>', {
        text: data.B
  }));
  tr.append($('<td>', {
        text: data.C
  }));
  tbody.append(tr);


});
```

you will get your expected output.As far as i know, using jQuery instead of simple javascript is always easy and less confusing.

Comment: My object isn't that. I know how its done if its a NICE data set as you have assumed.